# Why are my React form submission values undefined?

Tags: reactjs, forms, undefined

I'm trying to create a form and store the values of it in state – so far, so reasonable.

I think I've set it all up right, but when I return the contents of state, each and every field comes back undefined. I don't doubt that there's something simple I've overlooked in setting it up, but I can't for the life of me see what it is...

Can someone put me out of my misery?

```
handleAddProperty = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.fields);
  console.log(this.state.fields.type);
};

handleFieldChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      fields: {
        title: event.target.value.title,
        type: event.target.value.type,
        bedrooms: event.target.value.bedrooms,
        bathrooms: event.target.value.bathrooms,
        price: event.target.value.price,
        city: event.target.value.city,
        email: event.target.value.email,
      },
    });
  };

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="addproperty">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddProperty}>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
          <input name="title" value={this.state.fields.title} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} />
          <select name="type" value={this.state.fields.type} onChange={this.handleFieldChange}>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Flat</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Detached</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Semi-Detached</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Terraced</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>End of Terrace</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Cottage</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.type}>Bungalow</option>
          </select>
          <input name="bedrooms" value={this.state.fields.bedrooms} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} />
          <input name="bathrooms" value={this.state.fields.bathrooms} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} />
          <input name="price" value={this.state.fields.price} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} />
          <select name="city" value={this.state.fields.city} onChange={this.handleFieldChange}>
            <option value={this.state.fields.city}>Manchester</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.city}>Leeds</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.city}>Sheffield</option>
            <option value={this.state.fields.city}>Liverpool</option>
          </select>
          <input name="email" value={this.state.fields.email} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using `handleFieldChange` as event handler for all inputs, but that doesn't mean that all of them will be run at the same time. If you e.g. write something in the `title` input, only that input will trigger an event and  `event.target.value` will be the `title` value.

Comment: Thanks for that @Tholle – that makes sense, but what do I need to change to rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access to `event.target.value` rather then to `event.target.value[key]` because `handleFieldChange` function triggers for each input field (when they change their state) and for each of that triggers `event.target`is referring to a different input field (basically the input which has been changed).

To update the state you can use `event.target.name` as a key to your form object members inside the component state. The code might look like the following:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { form: { name: 'Jane' } };
 }

 handleFieldChange(event) {
    // This will update specific key in your form object inside the local state
    this.setState({
      form: Object.assign({}, this.state.form, {
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }),
   });
 }


 <input
    name="test"
    type="text"
    onChange={e => this.handleFieldChange(e)}
 />
```